# Report Builder 2.0 query: ElementPath with a space in a field name

Tags: xml, soap, reporting-services, formatting, reportbuilder

I'm trying to use Report Builder 2.0 to query a Sharepoint List using an XML data source.  I explicitly list the fields I want returned because otherwise [I don't get all of them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179613/querying-data-from-sharepoint-using-report-builder-2-0-missing-fields), due to some of them being null sometimes.  However, one of the fields I need has a space in its name.  If I do a query where I don't explicitly specify fields, I get this back as one of the fields:  `ows_Pre-Req Estimate`.  How can I specify this field in the `ElementPath` tag?  I get different errors when I try to put the field name in quotes or just leave it with a space as shown:

```
<ElementPath IgnoreNamespaces="true">
GetListItemsResponse/GetListItemsResult/listitems/data/row{@ows_Release,@ows_Theme,@ows_ID,@ows_Pre-Req Estimate}
</ElementPath>
```

Here's the error I get when I leave the space in and try to run the query in Query Designer:

> The XmlDP query is invalid. Syntax error at line 1, character 105 of the ElementPath.  Expected }.

I tried checking the [MSDN page about ElementPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220472.aspx) but didn't see any notes about fields with spaces.  I saw on [Maria's two cents](http://blogs.msdn.com/mariae/archive/2007/12/13/querying-sharepoint-list-from-reporting-services-returns-only-not-null-columns.aspx) that someone suggested using `_x0020_` instead of a space but that doesn't seem to work either.

Cross-posted to [Microsoft Forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/0c3876ea-83f5-4379-b877-c44ecaedb8b3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ooh, here's some hairiness.  All right, so the commenter on Maria's Two Cents was right:  you can escape a space in `ElementPath` with `_x0020_`.  My problem was that you have to escape the hyphen in the field name, too.  I downloaded Report Builder 3.0 and tried creating the query in it.  Afterward, editing the XML of the query showed me the field names as they ought to be encoded:

```
<FieldRef Name="Pre_x002d_Req_x0020_Estimate" />
```

I can now use this in Report Builder 2.0 (note the "ows_" in front of the field names):

```
<ElementPath IgnoreNamespaces="true">
GetListItemsResponse/GetListItemsResult/listitems/data/row{@ows_Release,@ows_Theme,@ows_ID,@ows_Pre_x002d_Req_x0020_Estimate}
</ElementPath>
```